# How to disable "after confirmation" in team viewer for unattended setup

Tags: teamviewer

I want to set up unattended access to my home desktop. I added it to my TeamViewer account and it worked in past, however since some team view update it display this error every time I try to connect to it:

[image: TeamViewer Access Control Details]

I obviously can't do that because I am not physically near the computer. So when I get there, how do I change the "remote restrict access" so that I can access my PC using my TeamViewer account anything with no need to confirm anything on it?

Edit: I updated the question I wanted to ask how can I change this while I am physically at the computer so that this wouldn't pop up next time I want to use team viewer. I just can't find anything in TeamViewer config that would allow me to setup really unattended access.

Comment: AFAIK, Unless this computer is managed from a business (or whatever they call it) account, which support policies you can manage from the browser, you'll need to go to the actual computer and change the security settings there.

Comment: As @cascer1 mentioned, its likely that this needs to be done on the computer itself. If someone is near the computer, call them, take over the session and make them confirm it once so you can then change the settings back.

Comment: Can you not RDC on to the machine and change the settings for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

If you have physical access to the machine now (I think that's the edit), you can go to Extras - Options - Advanced and Show Advanced Options.

In here, under the heading: **Advanced settings for connections to this computer**, there is an option called **Access Control** that looking at the config you've posted above, is probably set to **Confirm all** - if you flip this to **Full Access** - you will be able to control that machine remotely without waiting for confirmations.

Disclaimer that I can't advise whether this is best practice, you need to be aware of the risks of setting up Full Access, use a good password etc. etc.